# Page borders in Apache FOP

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

What is the easiest way to draw page borders in PDFs using Apache FOP?

I can do it by putting `<fo:block-container border=...>` elements inside `<fo:flow flow-name=...>` elements referenced by `<fo:region-before region-name=...>`, `<fo:region-after region-name=...>`, `<fo:region-start region-name=...>`, `<fo:region-end region-name=...>`, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`fo:region-body`, etc., can have borders (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-body, and so on).

Just specify the border when you specify the region inside the `fo:simple-page-master`.

Comment: There's no such element `fo:simple-page-sequence`

Comment: I also get errors `Border and padding for fo:region-body "xsl-region-body" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position 4:125)` and 
`Border and padding for fo:region-after "xsl-region-after" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position 6:117)`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for dashing off an answer close to midnight.  It's not going to help you that it works with AH Formatter.  An alternative way is to put the content of your `fo:flow` inside a single-cell table.  Another option is to use a background image on the `fo:region-body`.